# Make a list of properties, which, if true for a graph G, are true for any supergraph of G

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be an arbitrary undirected simple graph.

Make a list of some properties, which, if true for a graph $G$, are true for any super-graph of $G$.

For example, if there exists $p \in \{n\in \mathbb{N}: n \geq 2\}$ such that $G$ contains a cycle of length $2^p$ then any $H$, super-graph of $G$, there exists $p \in \{n\in \mathbb{N}: n \geq 2\}$ such that $H$ contains a cycle of length $2^p$

The properties you list must be substantially different from each-other. For example do not start listing from $k = 3$ to $100$, that if there exists a cycle of length $k$ in G, then there exists a cycle of length $k$ in any super graph of $G$.

---

I have posted this question before, and the question was closed.
One of the persons who voted to close the question wrote to me,

> "Homework problems are generally not appropriate on any stackexchange
>   site without showing that you have worked on them […] this is a
>   clearly undergraduate-level problem [...]”

I believed that it was easier to answer my original question without knowing ***why*** I was asking it. However, I see now that I must justify my motivations. It is clear to me now that questions have no merit in their own right. I am sorry for my mistake. My motivations are described below:

---

### LEMMA 1

> Any graph on $n$ nodes and minimum degree greater than or equal to
>   $\delta$ has at least $(\delta/2)*n$ edges.
>
> For example, a graph of
>   min degree $\geq$  4 has at least 2*n edges;
>   a graph of min
>   degree $\geq$ 6 has at least 3*n edges;
>   and so on…

---

### DEFINITION OF $F$

> For any natural number $n$, let $F(n) = 1 + \lfloor n/2\rfloor* \lceil n/2 \rceil$

For large $n$, $F(n)$ approaches $1/2$ of the maximum possible number of edges in a graph.

---

### THEOREM 1

> For any graph, $G$, if $G$ contains at least $F(|V(G)|)$ edges, then there exists graph $G^{\prime}$, sub-graph of $G$, such that $|V(G^{\prime})| \leq |V(G)| - 1$ and $G^{\prime}$ has at least $F(|V(G^{\prime})|)$ edges

Proof:

Let $G$ be a graph having at least $F(|V(G)|)$ edges.
For example, if $G$ has 18 nodes, then $G$ has at least 82 edges.

Let $G^{\prime}$ be a graph induced from $G$ by arbitrarily removing zero or more edges from $G$ such that $G^{\prime}$ has exactly $F(|V(G)|)$ edges.

If $G^{\prime}$ contains a sub-graph containing at least $F(|V(G)|)$ edges, then so does graph $G$

Let $\delta =  \lfloor|V(G^{\prime})|/2 + 1\rfloor$

Given that we have $F(|V(G)|)$ edges, by ***LEMMA 1***, $min degree (G^{\prime}) \leq (delta – 1)$

Let $v$ be  vertex of minimum degree in graph $G^{\prime}$

Let $G^{\prime\prime}$ be graph $G^{\prime}$ with vertex $v$ removed.

It follows that $F(|V(G^{\prime\prime})|) \leq  F(|V(G)|) – \delta \leq |E(G^{\prime\prime})|$

Therefore, $G^{\prime\prime}$ is a sub-graph of $G$ containing fewer vertices than $G$ such that $G^{\prime\prime}$ contains at least $F(|V(G^{\prime\prime})|)$ edges.

$QED$

---

### THEOREM 2

> Let $P$ be a property on graphs such that for any graph $G$, $P(G)$ implies $P(H)$ for any $H$ supergraph of $G$
>
> If there exists natural $n$ such that for every graph, $G$, having $n$ nodes and $F(n)$ edges, $G$ has property $P$, then it follows that $P(H)$ for every graph $H$ such that $H$ has at least $F(|V(H)|)$ edges, so long as $|V(H)| \geq n$.

Proof:

We proceed by induction. We induct on the number of vertices in the graph

Base case:

There exists natural $n$ such that for every graph, $G$, having $n$ nodes and $F(n)$ edges, $G$ has property $P$.

Let $H$ be a super-graph of $G$ such that $H$ has at least $F(n)$ edges and $V(H) = V(G)$. By the definition of property $P$, we have $P(H)$.

Thus, $P(J)$ for all graphs $J$ having $n$ nodes and at least $F(n)$ edges

The inductive step follows from theorem 1.

$QED$

---

I basically want to know what implications of theorem 2 are interesting.

For example, any graph on $4$ vertices and at least $F(4) = 5$ edges, contains a power cycle.Therefore, any graph having at least 4 vertices and at least $F(|V(G)|)$ edges contains a power cycle. A power cycle is a cycle of length $2^p$ for integer $p \geq 2$

Ignoring power cycles, what else might we say?

Comment: This looks very similar to the graph minor theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson–Seymour_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connectivity, Hamiltonicity, non-planarity, the property of containing any given graph as a subgraph...

The properties that have the property you want are known as "increasing graph properties," at least in the random graphs literature. See, for instance, [Introduction to Random Graphs](https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/BOOK.pdf) by Frieze and Karonski.

Comment: Increasing graph properties are preserved if you add edges; I think that the question is about properties that are also preserved if you add vertices, which is a bit more limiting.